# How to change woocommerce price according to user input

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have used the hook woocommerce_before_calculate_totals but stuck in getting dynamic value in my function. Even i have used session but it didn't work on passing dynamic price.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet adds 100 to all the products in the cart, you can put your own conditions and pricing calculation there.

```
function calculate_product_price( $cart_object ) {
        /* Gift wrap price */
        $additionalPrice = 100;
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {               
            //You can add your condition here
            $quantity = floatval( $value['quantity'] );
            $orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->price );
            $value['data']->price = ( ( $orgPrice + $additionalPrice ) * $quantity );                   
        }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_product_price', 1, 1 );
```